# Deletion of Windows profile image not working - what to do?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am trying to delete a profile/account image:

1. I have deleted the file in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\AccountPictures`
2. Then I have also deleted the profile image in the corresponding Microsoft account, as it appeared to be the same image.

Nevertheless, the image is still visible in the logon screen. Any ideas?

Comment: Please see if this Microsoft article helps. There is always an image holder and that is fixed in place.   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-your-account-picture-3645cdc7-acab-49d2-76a9-4ce7e5e10939

Comment: Did you pick a replacement image yet?

Comment: I can replace the image, but NOT delete it

Answer (score 1):

Another place where account images are kept is in the folder
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\User Account Pictures`.

Look for your picture in there and delete, then reboot.

This is in addition to
`%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\AccountPictures`
and the picture in your Microsoft account.

Comment: The `ProgramData` folder does not exist here.  The other one is the same I have used. Thanks anyway. The MS profile photo is void - just rechecked.

Comment: It's not possible that `ProgramData` does not exist. If your Windows is not in English, the name might be different.

Comment: Sorry - misleading comment: the folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\User Account Pictures` does not exist. Wanted to write "subfolder does not exist". My bad. 

However, just by checking again I have noticed a folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Default Account Pictures` . Will try this one and report back!